# How can I create Jalali Date Picker in Kendo UI?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, datepicker

I need Jalali date picker but Kendo UI currently supports only the Gregorian calendar, so please give me advice and guide me, how can i add it as a feature for my web application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kendo UI do not support Persian calendar but there is a Persian date picker that is built on top of KendoUI libraries. [Here](http://www.alirezazahedi.com/?p=337) you can use it.

[image]

EDIT: the link seems not working anymore!

Comment: how about datetimepicker. i do it but its js  doesnt work on datetimepicker. work on datepicker timepicker calendar

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi Unfortunately I don't have any idea

Comment: It's not any more accessible

Comment: Fake Link, The Link is using for commercial!

Answer (score 1):

See the link below to use the latest version of the solar calendar based on the Kendo UI calendar.

**Note:** Using these files, you can use kendoDatePicker and kendoCalendar **(English and Persian) together**.

For Html version (Java based):
[KendoUI Persian Solar (Shamsi-Jalali) Calendar for Kendo UI](https://github.com/MahdiNosratian/KendoUI-Persian-Calendar)

For MVC version (Asp.net MVC based):
[KendoUI Persian Solar (Shamsi-Jalali) Calendar for Kendo UI in MVC applications.](https://github.com/MahdiNosratian/KendoUI-Persian-Calendar-MVC)

Comment: Jquery version is not compatible with the 2021 KENDO UI FOR JQUERY